# Load UIWebView in background (invisible) on any ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I want to load a UIWebView in the background, so that it does not take any input from the user nor that the user can see it. I also don't know in what view the user will be when I need to load the UIWebView, and I don't want to copy/paste my code in all my ViewControllers. How do I do this?

Comment: You may try to just create the UIWebView and load content into it without adding that view to another view.

Comment: Since that view won't load anywhere, what method do I call to call my function? ViewWillAppear or DidLoad won't work for that matter

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. You mean where do you create the UIWebView? That's up to you, depending on when you want it to be created.

Comment: That's part of my question: I don't know when to load this View. I've got a method to check wheter to load or not, but I don't know in which view the user will be when it's needed.

Comment: Well if you don't know when to load it, surely we can't either! What the criteria for it being "needed"? Though I have to admit I don't understand why you would need a UIWebView that is not visible. You probably want to do just an HTTP request instead.

Comment: Ah yeah I need to check if an API key is still valid, but I need to do that for every hour, and it could be that the user is in a different view when that happens. HTTP request sounds more like it, will check that out. Thanks so far ;)

Comment: UIWebviews aren't UIViewControllers and don't have a ViewWillAppear or ViewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by just calling a `http` request intead, using the following method:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
            if (error)
            {
               NSLog(@"Error,%@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
            else
           {
              NSLog(@"1");
           }
}];
```